# Integrating the Spotify API with Desktop App using C++ stream music and get metadate

Tags: spotify, desktop-application

i didnt found any information if i can stream music and get songs metadata in 
desktop API ? without using some kind of local server and emulate web api
any idea ? 
i want to use stream music and get metadate  in c++ app